# Delete old records with SQLAlchemy/PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I automatically delete records that have expired, say records that are 5 days old using SQLAlchemy or PostgreSQL? Is there a way to do this without crontab? I would like to implement something like Pastebin's expiration system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pgAdmin to create a [schedule](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.22/pgagent-schedules.html) performing the action you need.